# How to get Firebase cloud messages inside the app , not Push notifications

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an android app with working firebase cloud messaging, every time when a new message arrives there is a Push notification. I don't want this push notification I want to view this notification inside the app as in so many social apps like facebook. I have Implemented a notification counter but how to add view like this?

[image]

I have been searching for this since tomorrow but I didn't get my answer, Is there any possibility to get Firebase messages inside my android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did something similar to this using [Firebase RTDB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/), FCM, and Cloud Functions. Basically, the idea is that you add the data to the DB, under a node corresponding to the user, like so:

```
/notifications
  /$userId
    /$notificationId
      /detail1:..
      /detail2:..
```

Then implement the [Database Trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) to trigger a Push Notification. However, what you want is to *not send a push notification*, so you can skip the FCM and Cloud Functions part. Just focus on using Firebase RTDB.

This is the best approach I can think of to go for the behavior you want. But if your goal is to simply catch the notification, you would have to implement a `data`-only payload for FCM, then in `onMessageReceived()`, store the message details somewhere where your app could later get.

Comment: If by *within the device* you mean storing it locally, I think you could use SQLite. But why not take advantage of FIrebase? Storing the notification details locally would only make it available for that specific device, so if the user signs in a different device, those details won't be available unless you sync it in your data storage.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public final class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        //storage messages here
    }
}
```

And then it on your AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
 </intent-filter>
```

About **FirebaseMessagingService**

> Extending this class is required to be able to handle downstream messages. It also provides functionality to automatically display notifications, and has methods that are invoked to give the status of upstream messages.
>
> Override base class methods to handle any events required by the application. Methods are invoked on a background thread.

Comment: Bro thanks for your Answer , but I have Already done this all,  I want to create such type of view which I have mentioned, how is it possible? in other words I want push notifications like notifications inside my App..